# Referring to a column in data frame with paste0 name

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame with name paste0(i, "_SA") which is created in a loop.I want to print the 4th column but neither $ nor [,4] works. paste0(i, "_SA")[,4] gives error "incorrect number of dimensions" even though if I use this outside of the loop like US_SA[,4] it works. How do you refer to a column of paste0 named data frame?

Comment: @samadhi No, won't work

Comment: It will work. Wrap ` around column name and use $ to get column. I just tested it

Comment: @samadhi Only if your dataset object name is `paste0(i, "_SA")`  The OP asked for dynamic replacement of `i` and the OP already mentioned `if I use this outside of the loop like US_SA[,4] it works`

Comment: That's what is being said in question. There's a data frame with name `paste0(i, "_SA")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use get to get the values of the object

```
for(i in c("US", "UK")) {
       print(get(paste0(i, "_SA"))[, 4])
  }
```

It can be also loaded into a `list` after `paste`ing with `mget` (as `paste` is vectorized)

```
lst1 <- mget(paste0(c("US", "UK"), "_SA"))
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot!!